# Disable access to .css files (a specific folder in main resource folder)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have searching the web for hours for this solution. I want to have access on `localhost/index.html` but not in `localhost/layout/style.css`.

My static resources are from external folder and the filee tree goes as the obvious:

```
->site
   ->layout
      ->style.css
   ->index.html
```

So far, all things i have tried, either disable access to index.html, either both index and style.css have access.

The thing i found online that makes the most sense is:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*.html").permitAll();
        // http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
        super.configure(http);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/layout/**");
        super.configure(web);
    }
```

but when i use `localhot/layout/style.css` it shows the css file.

my `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:mylocation/site/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/index.html");
    }
}
```

Annotations on start up:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer
```

What would be the way to be able to see index.html but not all the css files inside layout folder?

P.S: Maybe this is not even possible?

Comment: Main question here: why do you need it? What is your usecase/concern here? I don't think it is how it supposed to work. Your style.css most probably is used in index.html or another html, so it has to be accessible.

Comment: @SergeiSirik So, disabling access to style.css means the index cannot have access too? hmmm Maybe i am missing something here,...What if i make it have access only from localhost?

Comment: @George Zougianos what do you mean `index` cannot access it? The user who will request `index` page will see it without styles.

Comment: @J-Alex I can understand the whole point of permission, but do these permissions work like OS permissions (r/w)? I mean, i request index.html and somewhere in index, i read the style.css. It will go and request the /style.css or just read the file?

Comment: @George Zougianos, user's browser will not have access to styles. css the same as html is just a resource for user's browser to display it, so if you disable access to css it will not be able to display styles in your htmls.

Comment: @George Zougianos, Take a look at this diagram for example: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/php-mysql/9781449355517/httpatomoreillycomsourceoreillyimages1416222.png

Comment: @SergeiSirik Ok, it makes sense. However, even if users can't see the styles, how could i achieve it? I mean, i spent like 3 hours trying to configuring security, so all HTML files have access but things in layout don't. Just for the sake of the knowledge :P

Comment: @George Zougianos, not sure that is related to security in any sense. You can implement a filter for example and check file extension, if it is css you can return whatever you want, 404 for example. Or simply delete your css files since you don't want anybody to have access to it.